# Sound is not working

Tags: 12.04, sound, lubuntu

I've rebooted `Lubuntu 12.04` 64-bit a few times and still the sound doesn't work. **I'm not sure what terminal commands to paste to be helpful.**

Here are the outputs of a few that I see requested in other [sound] threads:

`$ aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD198x Analog [AD198x Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: AD198x Digital [AD198x Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`$ lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI M52 [Mobility Radeon X1300]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
15:00.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1510 PC card Cardbus Controller
```

`$ grep "Codec:" /proc/asound/card*/codec*`

```
Codec: Analog Devices AD1981
```

Comment: please provide more onfo like when does it not work? what errors are you getting (if any) ?

Comment: @Ashu Like no sound works at all -- videos, `zomg` with local files, last.fm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Login or event sound then here's what you can do -

Procedure 1:

Install dconf editor. goto org->gnome->desktop->sound

change the sound theme "freedesktop" to "ubuntu"

If not worked then;

Procedure 2:

gksudo nautilus (press alt+f2)

```
go to /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
```

copy the sound files

Paste them to

```
 /usr/share/sounds
```

---

Install "Gnome Alsa Mixer". Use the sound controls in it to set Volume to max Value.

Comment: Hi, my directory structure only goes out to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/` with no `stereo`. As mentioned in the second comment on the OQ, the problem is with Youtube, `zomg`, every kind of sound. BTW, I have `alsamixer` and `Lubuntu` doesn't use `GNOME`.

Comment: Do you have flash and other media playback plugins installed (Gstreamer, divx, quicktime, shockwave, totem, xine etc) ?

Comment: For last.fm you need Gstreamer. The best I can suggest install all Gstreamer related packages. (This is what I did when my Radio Tray was not working).

Comment: Maybe I should restate it this way. Up until several days ago I was able to play music just fine. A few days ago Spotify quit in the middle of operation and since then I haven't been able to restore sound, not even by rebooting.

Comment: So I do have gstreamer, quicktime, etc. I was able to play Youtube vids, `zomg`, Spotify, last.fm, you name it, until a few days ago.